# Cannot assign a value of type '[String]' to a value of type '[MovieVO]' - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchresultscontroller

```
class ListViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var list = [MovieVO]()
    var filteredlist = [MovieVO]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    self.filteredlist.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

     let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
     let array = (self.list as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)


     self.filteredlist = array as! [String] => Cannot assign a value of type '[String]' to a value of type '[MovieVO]'

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `self.filteredlist` as a Swift array of `MovieVO` types, so no, you cannot assign to it an array of `String` types.  Try and cast it to a `MovieVO` type or otherwise convert it to that type (perhaps it would be useful to see your definition of `MovieVO`).

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `filteredlist` as an array of `MovieVO` when you did:

```
var filteredlist = [MovieVO]()
```

So it can't accept `[String]`, only `[MovieVO]`.

I guess instead of casting your NSArray to `[String]` you wanted to cast it back to `[MovieVO]`:

```
self.filteredlist = array as! [MovieVO]
```

And to avoid crashes, replace this forced cast with optional binding:

```
if let movies = array as? [MovieVO] {
    self.filteredlist = movies
}
```

Comment: can you write solved code on here? i am sorry. i don't understand your reply. please help me.

Comment: There's nothing to add, the fixed code is already in my answer. Read it carefully. :)